# Windows XP password protection lockout

Tags: windows, windows-xp, screensaver, password-protection

We are working on client-provided VMs.  We connect to these VMs using Remote Desktop, and each VM is running Windows XP.

After some time, the machine gets locked and we need to re-enter the password to continue working.  Unfortunately, this is causing our automated scripts to fail.

Note: we have already disabled the screen saver.

Comment: Yes it is XP Professional.

Answer (score 1):

There are three other likely places where the machine can be automatically locked:

1. Power management settings can be set to automatically lock after coming back from standby but this shouldn't apply with a VM (check anyway though, only takes a second).
2. Group policy may be set to force the computer to lock every so often (VERY likely if these VMs are joined to a domain)
3. Logging out of remote desktop should lock the machine, but you can supply credentials so it's unlocked as you connect.

Answer (score 0):

Check your power management settings -- make sure it's all turned off since the environment is contained within a Virtual Machine (so there's no point in using power management in the Guest OSes).

There is a setting in Power Management that will require the user to enter their password when leaving the power-saving state, so you might want to double-check this option while you're at it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you disconnect from an RDP session, it locks the user session.  Take a look at a different remote console app (vnc, Remote Adminstrator, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If it is XP Pro, the easiest way to fix this is to change the Terminal Services settings using gpedit.msc on the computer you are connecting to.

You then navigate to:

```
Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Terminal Services>Sessions
```

Set these setting:

1. Sets a time limit for active Terminal Services sessions
2. Sets a time limit for active but idle Terminal Services sessions
3. Terminate session when time limits are reached

Then run gpupdate /force at a command prompt.

If these are on a domain, you may need to also set these in the domain group policy, or they will be overwritten every 90 minutes.

These settings handle how RDP sessions are handled.

[image]

Comment: As a side note, your scripts should probably be set up as scheduled tasks, so they will not be dependent on your being logged in.

Comment: I tried reaching the Terminal Services section, but it is not available there.

Comment: Right-click on "Administrative Templates" and click Add/Remove templates. Is the "system" template installed? If not, click Add, and select it from the list (should default to the windows\inf folder, if not navigate there).

Comment: Just to be clear, you run this on the computer you are trying to connect to, not your computer.